# unable to call keras module in python

Tags: python, keras

I am working on keras. I am new to kears. Here is my code for creating movie vectors and user vectors. After applying flatten its gives empty tensor.

```
movie_input = keras.layers.Input(shape=[1])
movie_vec = keras.layers.Flatten()(keras.layers.Embedding(n_movies + 1, 32) 
(movie_input))
movie_vec = keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(movie_vec)
print(movie_vec)

# Same thing for the users
user_input = keras.layers.Input(shape=[1])
user_vec = keras.layers.Flatten()(keras.layers.Embedding(n_users + 1, 32) 
(user_input))
user_vec = keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(user_vec)
print(user_vec)

input_vecs = keras.layers.merge([movie_vec, user_vec], mode='concat')
nn = keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')    (input_vecs))
nn = keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization()(nn)
nn = keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(nn))
nn = keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization()(nn)
nn = keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(nn)
```

It gives me this error

```
>TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
>cc<ipython-input-27-10f282af0460> in <module>()
 18 # Next, we join them all together and put them
 19 # through a pretty standard deep learning architecture
 20 input_vecs = keras.layers.merge([movie_vec, user_vec], mode='concat')
 21 nn = keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(keras.layers.Dense(128,activation='relu')(input_vecs))
 22 nn = keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization()(nn)
 >TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: which version you are using

Answer (score 1):

Use keras 2.1.5

keras.layers.merge method available in it

Comment: I have downgraded my keras version to 2.1.5. It's working for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`keras.layers.merge` is not a callable. It is a module. Check out its [documentation](https://keras.io/layers/merge/)